# rename regex is failing to rename files

Tags: regex, rename

I have a bunch of images like `1.jpg 2.PNG 3.gif 4.jpeg` in a directory.  I want to rename them all to `1-s.jpg 2-s.PNG 3-s.gif 4-s.jpeg`.

I tried running these commands but it had no effect on files in the directory:

```
rename 's/^(\d+)\.(.*)/$1-s.$2/' .
rename 's/^(\d+)\.(.+)/$1-s.$2/' .
rename 's/.*\.(.+)/$1-s.$2/' .
```

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the wildcard `*` for filenames:

```
rename 's/^(\d+)\.(.*)/$1-s.$2/' *
```

and you can simplified a bit:

```
rename 's/^(\d+)(?=\.)/$1-s/' *
```

where `(?=\.)` is a positive lookahead that make sure we have a dot after the digit, without capture it.